# Number of Distinct Roots of Unity

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

The roots of unity are the solutions to:

$$z^n=1,z\in \mathbb{C},n\in \mathbb{N}\implies(rcis\theta)^n=1\implies r=1,\theta=\frac{2\pi k}{n},k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

A primitive root of unity for $n$ is a root that is not a root for any lower value of n. I want to count the number of elements in the set of solutions to :
$$z^n=1, 1<n<10$$

If $n$ is small, it can be done manually. But if $n$ is large the process becomes tedious. Is there a more elegant way to approach this problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#General_definition

Comment: I dont want the definition. That I already mentioned. I want the number of distinct roots.

Comment: have patience & read the full content ,

Comment: So is it to do with Euler's Totient Function? I need to sum it over 1 to n?

Comment: @Starlight Could you maybe add an example?